# Android - How to put a item click in ListView with Hashmap and List

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

In my app, I use an `AsyncTask` named `GetImageTask` to get an image from an `URL` with an int given by the user.

Example : url = "http://example.com/image.php?index=" + int

I put the image in a `ImageView` and in my `"doInBackground"`, I create two `HashMap` for add element in two list.

The first is for display the list of index in my `ListView` when I click in the button `"onClickIndex"`.

The second one is for save my Image with the index given because I want the element of `ListView` to get back the image when user click on it (`onClickIndex`).

But I'm blocked on this part because I can't get the Bitmap in my second list with the index and don't know what to do ?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private EditText MyNumber;
private ImageView MyImage;
private ListView MyIndexList;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Bitmap>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MyNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.choiceofindex);
    MyImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageRecup);
    MyIndexList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listIndex);

}

class GetImageTask extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Bitmap> {

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... index) {
        HashMap<String,String> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Integer,Bitmap> hashmap2 = new HashMap<>();
        Integer choix = index[0];
        String urldisplay = "http://example.com/image.php?index=" + choix;
        Bitmap RecupImage = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            RecupImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        hashmap.put("index","index " +choix);
        hashmap2.put(choix,RecupImage);
        list.add(hashmap);
        list2.add(hashmap2);
        return RecupImage;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        MyImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Image!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public void onClickRecup(View v)
{
    try{
        int index= Integer.parseInt(MyNumber.getText().toString());
        GetImageTask GetImage = new GetImageTask();
        GetImage.execute(index);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(context, "No image!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public void onClickIndex(View v)
{
    try {
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,list,R.layout.row, new String[]{"index"},
                new int[] {R.id.index});
        MyIndexList.setAdapter(adapter);
        MyIndexList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Bitmap Imageback = list2.get(position).get(R.id.index);
                MyImage.setImageBitmap(Imageback);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Problem on ListView", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }


  }
```

Comment: Honestly, I'm curious. Does this compile/run to some degree?

Comment: Yes I can get the images and a list of index in a ListView. I just can't figure how to join the index (in list) with the bitmap associated (in list2).

Comment: Alright. This is overly complicated. Let me ask before I answer the question: do you have to use hashmaps for any particular reason?

Comment: No, I just use them for save elements in my two list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner but I was busy.

Don't use a hashmap to store the Bitmaps. It's over complicating things.

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

then change this line..

```
Bitmap Imageback = list2.get(position).get(R.id.index);
```

to this

```
Bitmap ImageBack = list2.get(position);
```

The reason why what you wrote didn't work is that you don't store the images on key: R.id.index

```
Integer choix = index[0];
...
hashmap2.put(choix,RecupImage);
```

*R.id.index* is an integer that is generated by R before the app is run that uniquely identifies anything with that label. This is why it wouldn't accept it before (as far as I can tell)

Comment: Question - How would RecyclerView work in a scenario like this?

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and the explanation. It works well ! Just an another little question, when I download my image from the url I get the message "Image!!" when it's done but not the "wait..." message in the "onProgressUpdate" I don't know why ?

Comment: @Tenebros generally using getApplicationContext() is avoided and I think this *may* be your problem. Try this: MainActivity.this

Comment: Ok I will test this when I go home.

Comment: Nothing happen but I find the solution to call "onProgressUpdate" in the "doInBackground" with publishProgress() and the Toast appear. Thank you again iismathwizard !